# run a php script in centos and time and timeout

Tags: centos, php

I want to run a php script in centos ( `/usr/bin/php file.php` ), and it takes long time to execute,and in the middle of executing , it stops running , and does not give me any errors.
and I'm sure that there is absolutely no error in my php code (I tested it in many way) , I think it's the matter of time of executing.
my question is :

- is it possible that it's  timeout error from my server that stops the script from executing ?
- if yes, how can I set the server to gives timeout error in a longer time?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840711/how-to-execute-a-large-php-script

Answer (score 2):

Any PHP script executed from the command-line or from a shell script, cron job, etc. does not have a timeout.

You can't even deliberately set a max execution time when you're invoking PHP from the CLI. You can call `set_time_limit(n)` but this has no effect.

For example, if the max_execution_time affected the CLI, the following script should not print "done" but it does:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(5);
print ini_get('max_execution_time') . "\n";
sleep(10);
print "done.\n";
```

It's possible that you have an error that is not being reported. Make sure you enable full error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: but I'm sure that my php script gas no error, I just don't know why it stops after some minute, are you saying there is NO time out error in running a php script on command line or cron job ?

Comment: That was the point of my code example above. Even if you *try* to make the script have a timeout, it won't work if you invoke the script from the command-line.

Comment: so what do you think about my problem ? consider my script without error

Comment: You haven't shown your script or your usage of it.

Comment: its complicated and its in my own framework, you cant understand the code well,its about 180 lines, thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is no error in your script and you are running it from the command line, here are some things you could do:

1. Test your theory about timeout: write a dummy script that does nothing for a very long time (like a nested loop), does it stop before it's done?
2. Profile your code's memory requirements: https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler.
3. Try running the same script: though unlikely, there might be a problem with the Environment.

There is no reason that you shouldn't be able to run a script if there are no errors and the needed resources are available.